# apt コマンド実行時に必要な認証プロキシのログイン情報を適切に保存するには？

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

Debian ベースの Linux で `apt` コマンドの実行時、社内ネットワークから外部との接続に認証プロキシを通す必要がある場合、apt.conf に以下のような記述をすれば接続自体は可能です。

**/etc/apt/apt.conf:**

```
Acquire {
    http::proxy "http://username:password@proxy.example.jp:8080";
}
```

しかし、個人のログイン情報を誰でも参照できる場所に記載してしまうのはあまり好ましくないため、何か適切な設定方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt.conf を任意のパスに保存して、`apt` コマンドの実行時に `-c` オプションで指定する方法があります。

ホームディレクトリの `~/apt.conf` を指定する場合:

```
$ sudo apt -c=~/apt.conf update
```

また、毎回オプションで指定するのが面倒であれば、環境変数 `APT_CONFIG` に設定ファイルのパスを指定しておけば自動で認識するようになります。

```
$ export APT_CONFIG=~/apt.conf
$ sudo apt update
```

ログインシェルの設定ファイル (`~/.bashrc`) などに記載しておくとよいかもしれません。